# Get first and last day of previous week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ms-access

Please can someone provide code for the first and last day of last week?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Some common date routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/).

Comment: What *is* the first day of your week? It's culture dependant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these functions:

```vb
Public Function DateWeekFirst( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal lngFirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
  As Date

' Returns the first date of the week of datDate.
' lngFirstDayOfWeek defines the first weekday of the week.
' 2000-09-07. Cactus Data ApS.
' 2003-05-01. System settings used as default.
' 2012-10-44. Data type of lngFirstDayOfWeek changed to VbDayOfWeek.

  DateWeekFirst = DateAdd("d", vbSunday - Weekday(datDate, lngFirstDayOfWeek), datDate)

End Function

Public Function DateWeekLast( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal lngFirstDayOfWeek As Long = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
  As Date

' Returns the last date of the week of datDate.
' lngFirstDayOfWeek defines the first weekday of the week.
' 2000-09-07. Cactus Data ApS.
' 2003-05-01. System settings used as default.
' 2012-10-44. Data type of lngFirstDayOfWeek changed to VbDayOfWeek.

  DateWeekLast = DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(datDate, lngFirstDayOfWeek), datDate)

End Function
```

Then, for example:

```
FirstDatePreviousWeek = DateWeekFirst(DateAdd("ww", -1, Date))
```